# i get a lot of stdout logs with tomcat and even logback

Tags: java, hibernate, logback, tomcat8

i added logback libs (classic , core , access) and slf4j-api- 1.6.1
i created logback.xml file under src/main/resources

my questions is logback doesn't work and i can not get rid of hibernate DEBUG logs and all of std logs .. i want to see just ERROR logs... and save to specific folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was because of tomcat service that i installed on windows .. there is a setting in configuration that makes tomcat save stdout logs it a file automatically. you have to go to configuration of tomcat service and disable auto generation of std out log in the log tab of configuration page tomcat service. if you installed a windows service of tomcat you can find the setting of these with opening configuration tomcat in start menu programs -> tomcat .